# Fresh installation of Magento is broken

Tags: magento2

I have just installed Magento v2 on a fresh instance of CentOS (VPS). After overcoming various speedbumps (wrong PHP version, wrong MySQL version, php.intl not configured) and it appears that stylesheets haven't been installed correctly.

It appears that during the installation process, Magento have created a ton of new folders, but they're been given incorrect permissions, and, as such, files that were supposed to be inserted, haven't been.

Has anyone seen anything similar or have an idea what I might be able to try to resolve the issue?

The URL for my site is http://pearsonjames.com (don't worry, going to get an SSL cert and go HTTPS before going live.

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in Magento 2.0.6. You can optionally set [magento_umask](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/post-install-umask.html) file to get the correct set of permissions your server setup needs to properly run.

Comment: Hi, the version installed is 2.0.6, so do you suggest I follow the guide you posted or is that no longer relevant?

Comment: Yes, the guide is good for Magento >= 2.0.6

Comment: The info on file system permissions is [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html)